# binding the data in datalist

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services, c#-4.0

i want to bind the selected checkbox row in datalist ..inused this code but does not bind all records ..

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox chkb = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox();
string chkBoxIndex = string.Empty;

foreach (C1.Web.Wijmo.Controls.C1GridView.C1GridViewRow row in C1GridView1_listview.Rows)
{
    chkBoxIndex = (string)C1GridView1_listview.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
    chkb = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkBxSelect");

    if (chkb.Checked == true)
    {

        cmd = new SqlCommand("select sample_code,convert(varchar(10),purchase_date,101) as purchase_date,sample_image_id,sample,image,style,descript from sample_shopping,sample_image where sample_shopping.sample_code=sample_image.sample and type='IMG' and sample_code='" + chkBoxIndex + "'", con);
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            dr.Close();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);

            dl_search.DataSource = dt;
            dl_search.DataBind();
            con.Close();

        }
    }
```

Comment: last record only binding.. how can i bind the more record in datalist

Comment: how can i multiple rows bind in datlist using this code\

Comment: jadarnel27//// can u solve the problem?

Comment: did you set autopostback property of checkbox to true?

Comment: yes is not a problem ...my question is how can i add multiple record bind the datalist

Comment: i want bind the loop in more row value in datalist ..

Comment: change the AutoPostBack property to false. because each time you check the checkbox request will be sent to server. that's why you read last record only. use html checkbox. have a trail.

Comment: k i changed ..i want to select 5 record means display the last record only all record replace one by one ..

Comment: i cant get you exactly. your selecting 5 records but it shows only one record?

Comment: i want store the value in datatable ...ex i select 5 sample code means 5 record display in datalist but last record only display

Comment: yes  i think store the data table and bind the list ..do u know ?

Answer (score 0):

your binding datalist in foreach loop only. that's why it is showing every time one record in datalist. make datalist binding out of foreach loop like

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox chkb = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox();
string chkBoxIndex = string.Empty;

    foreach (C1.Web.Wijmo.Controls.C1GridView.C1GridViewRow row in C1GridView1_listview.Rows)
    {
        chkBoxIndex = (string)C1GridView1_listview.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
        chkb = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkBxSelect");

        if (chkb.Checked == true)
        {
          //update the table with update query like
           //update <table-name> set check='true' where sno=chkBoxIndex or insert the select records into seperate table.
           ...
        }
    }
```

Now Bind the data to the datalist with the query like

```
 select * from <tablename> or where check=true
```

so that only selected rows will  be displayed in datalist. Hope this will help.